# How to increase width of my header to match the whole page width?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that has width more than 100%. The page is a datatable having many rows and I don't want to introduce an inner scroll-bar. Now I want to have my header expand width same as my overflowing table. How do I do that?

[image]

Please note that my header is 100% wide. I want to be more and matching the data-table width which is not hard coded.

Comment: add in your css html,body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

Comment: can you please create a fiddle. A simple nice looking image may not help us working with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

set this in your style sheet

```
html,body{
  width:100%; /* your remedy here */
  height:100%; /* your remedy here */
  margin:0 /* default set */
  padding:0; /* default set */
}
```

Comment: In addition to @noobeditor s answer you might  want to consider refactoring the parts of your html that are over 100%. It's not a good practice for the reasons you are running into now.